# In-app billing on google play store from javascript

Tags: javascript, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

how do I make in-app purchases from my javascript application which will be bundled into an apk? I discovered the google javascript api but it only allows you to verify whether purchases have been made, not to make actual transactions. I can't find any third party apps that bundle a hardware accelerated canvas with an HTML5 app, and provide plugins for android/iOS in-app purchases. Is there somewhere I can find the full REST api for the Google Play store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no REST API for in-app billing from Android applications. Your best bet is to write the code in Java and use JavaScript hooks in your HTML app to call them as necessary. Using [WebView.addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29), etc.

Comment: As far as I know javascript can't run java?

Comment: No, but you can call Java methods from JavaScript. See link in updated answer.